# How to access parent folders after .htaccess redirect?

Tags: php, css, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website that I need to be multilanguage. In a root folder I have an .htaccess that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs) [NC]
RewriteRule .* cs/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (de) [NC]
RewriteRule .* de/index.php [L]
```

I also have an index.php in root folder in default language (english). If a customer comes to the website, i need to redirect him to appropriate language file. The files are in the subfolders as you can see in the htaccess file. (/cs, /de). The reason why I have these files in subfolder is, that customers to have an opinion to change language themselves. There are flags on the website that redirect them to appropriate folder manually. 
So far, everything worked fine, but there is a huge problem. After the automatic redirection, the website can't access the root subfolders with css and js files.
It behaves like the cs/index.php file is located in the root. I am accessing the files through relative links like ../css/ because folders with these files are located in root directory.

So, finally, my answer. What should I change to make it work appropriately?
Thanks for every idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change above rules to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs|de) [NC]
RewriteRule !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ %1/index.php [L,NC]
```

This will rewrite all requests except `.css, .js & various images types` to subfolders.

Also try adding this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.